# Cocos2d html5 onTouchEnded is not working

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-js, cocos2d-html5

In my simple project I use touch events to change a button states:
in this case everything works fine

```
cc.eventManager.addListener(
{
    event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ALL_AT_ONCE,
    swallowTouches: false,
    onTouchesBegan: onTouchesBegan,
    onTouchesEnded: onTouchesEnded
}, this);
```

but in this case my onTouchEnded function have never been called:

```
cc.eventManager.addListener(
{
    event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,
    swallowTouches: false,
    onTouchBegan: onTouchBegan,
    onTouchEnded: onTouchEnded
}, this);
```

After some time with debugging I found "if" statement in cc.eventManager._onTouchEventCallback function:

```
} else if (listener._claimedTouches.length > 0
    && ((removedIdx = listener._claimedTouches.indexOf(selTouch)) != -1))
{
```

In my case "listener._claimedTouches" == 0 and the if statement denies calling onTouchMove and onTouchEnded listeners.

Does anyone have an idea why "listener._claimedTouches" == 0 and why such a thing is happened?

Comment: I dont see any problem in this code. Could you upload the entire code to see what's wrong? Also I usually refer to me function as this.nameFunction in the listener. I don't think this is the solution, because should be in scope, but just in case. Sometimes scopes in js are misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a "return true;" statement at the end of your onTouchBegan. onTouchEnd would be triggered when onTouchBegan returns true.

```
var listener = cc.EventListener.create({
    event:cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,
    swallowTouches:false,
    onTouchBegan: function(touch, event) {
        return true;
    },
    onTouchEnded: function(touch, event) {
        //do sth.
    }
});
cc.eventManager.addListener(listener, this);
```

Comment: Yep, this is the correct answer + mentioned in the documentation. Good job, @swen!